# Error: " event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' " on Discord.py when trying to make bot react to word in message

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay, I think this was answered before (didn't understand the answer) but I literally just jumped into python a few days ago to make this bot and am quite new to python (and this site) so bear with me.

okay so basically I'm trying to make one function of my bot react with any message containing a set word and reply to it. In this case, I just have it set to the number four. I am using the message.content command do this, however i run into this error: [Exception has occurred: TypeError
event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro']. Here is the code for the function that isn't working.

```py
## It's 4
UClient = discord.Client()

@UClient.event
async def on_message(message):
##error appears here
 if message.content('4'):
    await message.channel.send("It's Four")
```

Also, IDK if this matters but I have the bot using a prefix($) for other commands

Answer (score 0):

`message.content` is `str` type, so how you do it is to check `if strA == strB` instead of calling `strA()` because String is not callable.

I'm not pretty sure how you get the event error, I adjusted and test your code below, It's works fine. If you still get problem, maybe show more code to us.

btw, the `prefix` doesn't affect `on_message`, you'll receive the message first(on_message), then Discord.py using your prefix to find commands.

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == '4':
        await message.channel.send("It's Four")
```

Comment: idk what you did but it works now, I'll play around with it to try and see what caused the problem. Thanks man.